# how to minimize JBOSS AS 7 configuration to fit needs

Tags: jboss7.x

i need to be able to configure JBOSS as 7.2 to only startup the services required in the project.
what is the best aproach to customize JBOSS as 7.2 configuration and set it to a user defined configuration ?

i'm intending to use : 
JAAS , EJB , JSF ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your request correctly,
it would be removing the unnecessary subsystems.
In standalone, you can configure multiple xmls per your use, and decide the standalone config to use at startup, which would allow you to adapt to various needs quickly.

In domain, it's even easier as you can define various profiles, each of them with specific subsystems present or not, and then assign the necessary profile to your server group.

Removing subsystems through xml modification or CLI is simple,
adding them through CLI sometimes require figuring some  of the "default" expected entries for recreation of the subsystems, but once figured out, is easy also.

Key element in your case is to make sure you do not clean up too many of the subsystems, as they sometimes have dependencies to one another.